# Reactjs and tailwindcss make NavBar sticky does not work

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make my Navbar sticky on top of my browser using Tailwindcss.
I understand that the sticky property should be added on the first child of the root component, which is why I've added it on the `App.jsx` file.

See code below:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden ">
    
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    </header>

    <div className="bg-primary flex justify-center items-start">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Hero />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div className="bg-primary sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Block1/>
        <Block2 />
        <Block3 />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

However the navbar still gets moving out of the visible browser space once I scoll down.
I tried the fixed property, but in this case the navbar is not anymore centered and justified.

How can I get this navbar to remain sticky on top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden relative">
    
    <header className="fixed top-0 z-50 sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    </header>

    <div className="bg-primary flex justify-center items-start">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Hero />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div className="bg-primary sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
        <Block1/>
        <Block2 />
        <Block3 />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

OR,

just removed the overflow-hidden from parent div.

```
const App = () => (
      <div className="bg-primary w-full">
        
        <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
            <Navbar />
          </div>
        </header>
    
        <div className="bg-primary flex justify-center items-start">
          <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
            <Hero />
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="bg-primary sm:px-16 px-6 flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full">
            <Block1/>
            <Block2 />
            <Block3 />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to explain why the overflow-hidden conflicts with the sticky property? I don't want scrolls to appear if I get some text overflowing, especially on mobile displays

Comment: Any overflow value other than visible and no height is the enemy of child elements with position: sticky;. It’s like that element is ready to stick when the parent scrolls, but it never does because the height is unconstrained. Adding a fixed height can solve the issue, but that’s not always desirable.

Original link: https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/